# Display picture from database

Tags: c#, database, photo, display

I have a database with a photo column, I am trying to display it on a website.
I am coding in Visual studio 2019. It's an MVC project in c#

The two photos show what I got given. The link from the second picture doesn't go anywhere

[image: Photo1]

[image: Photo2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities:

1st option:

Store the path of the image in your database and dynamically set the `src` of an `<img>`

2nd option:

Save the image data in your database and reconstruct it on load, your `<img>` `src` has to be a controller action that loads, constructs and returns the image.

#### Edit

Quick example for option 2:

In your cshtml define your image like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetFromDB", "Image", new { id = 1234 })" />
```

Note, you can set the id of your picture dynamically, depending on your scenario. Lets say you have a user class which has a profile picture assigned, you just need to use this id.

On the backend you need a action that handles this request, in this example in the `ImageController`:

```
public ActionResult GetFromDB(int id)
{
    var image = _dbContext.Find(id);
    return File(image.PictureData, image.ContentType);
}
```

This assumes you have a simple database model for images like this:

```
class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte[] PictureData { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

To save your image to the database, you just need to get it's bytes and content type, for example like this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var uploadedImage = Image.FromStream(formFile.OpenReadStream(), true, true))
    {
        uploadedImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // you can actually chose this yourself, depending on your scenario
    }

    var image = new Model.Image()
    {
        PictureData = ms.ToArray(),
        ContentType = "image/jpeg" // needs to match what you chose above
    };
    _dbContext.Pictures.Add(image);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hey, the first option doesn't work. Can you explain the second option a little bit more in detail? I don't understand :D
The image data is saved in my database.

Comment: @Vox It depends on your scenario, could you explain me what doesn't work? I'll add an example for option 2 to the answer